# Java result after using a method isn't as expected

Tags: java

i have the following snipet of code :

```
class Phone {
    String phoneNumber = "123456789";
    void setNumber () {
        String phoneNumber;
        phoneNumber = "987654321";
    }
}
class TestPhone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Phone p1 = new Phone();
        p1.setNumber();
        System.out.println (p1.phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

im expecting "987654321" as result, but im getting "123456789"
it is like the method setNumber is without any effect
can anyone helps me to understand please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your re-declaring the phoneNumber variable inside the method, shadowing the field in the class, and so any changes made to the local variable will not be seen in the shadowed class field. Don't do this; get rid of the repeat variable declaration, so that changes made within the method will be seen in the field.

e.g., change this:

```
void setNumber () {
    String phoneNumber; // *** this is a local variable, visible ONLY in the method!
    phoneNumber = "987654321";  // this has no effect on the field
}
```

to this:

```
void setNumber () {
    // String phoneNumber;
    phoneNumber = "987654321"; // this will change the field!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels)

```
void setNumber () {
    String phoneNumber; 
    phoneNumber = "987654321";  
    this.phoneNumber = "9876"; //this will change your field and give expected result
}
```

is another way to guarantee to set value of field.

> In long methods local variable could shadow the field without being
>   aware so there may be local variables or not, always using `this` is a
>   good point to avoid shadowing

Answer (score 0):

Your variable inside the method is shadowing the class variable...

that is the reason of the weird beha...

Answer (score 0):

As already answered by other users, you're [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4) the variable `phoneNumber` by *declaring* it again in the scope of `setNumber` method.

The variable `phoneNumber` inside `setNumber` is not known outside its scope, and changing it *doesn't* affect the different `phoneNumber` variable declared as a *class member*.

That's why it's a good practice to refer to class members using [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) explicitly.

Side note: Try to use access modifiers instead of leaving it naked ([*no modifier*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) has a class and package access level). As a rule of thumb, always begin with the most restrictive access modifier, and expand it only when you must.